# Soft Keyboard stays up after initiating webview

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have an app that logs into a web application using some credentials. The login initiates the webview.

Here's the issue.

On the emulator (Nexus_S_Google and Nexus 5 with API 21) and a Samsung tablet the keyboard goes away when webview comes up. This would be the desired behavior. On two different phones (Samsung 5s and Samsung Galaxy Note 5) the keyboard does **not** go away. Is this just the way the phones work? Or is there a way to invoke this behavior? I don't understand why it works on the tablet and emulator but not the phones.

Here's what I tried.

In the Manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

In the Activity XML

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

In MainActivity after webview gets the url.

```
webView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Do you want the keyboard to keep out of sight until you close the webview, or do you just not want the keyboard to persist once you go to the webview? And is there any reason why you're requesting focus for your webview? Requesting focus usually ends up in popping up the keyboard

Comment: DERPA_CHIEF - Thank you for replying. I want the keyboard to go down when webview comes up, however it should pop back up if the person decides to edit something within the web application. Im thinking the webview will take care of that part. It is basically once webview launches the keyboard should go away. I did remove that focus for the webview and the behavior did not change. Each of the things I tried had no effect on the behavior.

Comment: What happens when you remove webView.requestFocus() and the focusable stuff in your layout xml?

Comment: Should I remove this line as well in the Manifest -             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

Comment: Up to you. I believe what it does is pan your webview when your keyboard pops up

Comment: After removing those items and recompile - 1. emulator and tablet show the keyboard on the app, then I fill in the credentials and click submit, opens up webview, keyboard disappears. Tested on the Galaxy Note 5 - The app comes up with keyboard as expected, I fill in credentials, click submit, webview initiates and fully loads the web app, keyboard stays up and doesn't disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76716/discussion-between-jay-and-derpa-chief).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it took a lot of trying but this is what I did to solve the issue.

Created method

```
private void fKeyboardClose()
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService( Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Then I called it right after the onClick for the submit button.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fKeyboardClose();

                textstring(phone, login, pass);
                prefwrite(editor);
                pushurl();
                clear(phone, login, pass);
```